# Where is the most clear and concise exposition of the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators on Hilbert space?

Tags: reference-request, operator-algebras

This question is certainly subjective, which may warrant votes to close. I'm simply looking to find the "best" written exposition of the spectral theorem for possibly unbounded self-adjoint operators (and so, perhaps including the proof of the spectral theorem for bounded normal operators). The hope is that I've missed a gold nugget in the literature.

Comment: I find this unclear, because I don't know which expositions you've already read and found unsatisfying.

Comment: @Jonas: Interpret it as "what is your favorite?". Another shortcoming of the question is that it assumes an objective standard for quality. I'm just ignoring that.